# Adding static variable to union of class types

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to represent the type *"a subclass of either `Base1` or `Base2`, with the addition of a static property `foo: string`"*.

I tried the following, but I get an error:

[(flow.org/try link)](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToBCWBTARlAG9QBfVDbPQgJjMuTSxwDFZZQCAPAFwIA7ACY58mYmUShQmfun4BLFKEhdQAXlAAiABZKdiKon4BPAA4FQASQnXtAYRqYAPPaIA+UAB9QztncGTwBuZHMrW05ubTtCUAAyMgBqdVgALjl+ACclIQBzEwAKaMybaIBKENkQUH4DHCUcSDyCZEgAVyEUZVghUHyCfmiiirLo6VlsoY7s-ujq0Fr6ptBVlqE24sHhrlHxriqasAJs7NhsxCA)

```
// @flow

class Base1 { }
class Base2 { }

class Foo extends Base1 {
  static foo = "hi"
}

type IBase = Class<Base1> | Class<Base2>;

type IFoo = IBase & {+foo: string}

(Foo: IFoo);  // no error

function getFoo(): IFoo {
  return Foo;  // no error
}

(getFoo(): IFoo);  // error
```

> Cannot cast `getFoo()` to `IFoo` because: Either `Base2` [1] is incompatible with `Base1` [2]. Or object type [3] is incompatible with statics of `Base1` [4]. Or `Base1` [2] is incompatible with `Base2` [1]. Or object type [3] is incompatible with statics of `Base2` [5].

I can fix the error by removing `& {+foo: string}` or by removing `| Class<Base2>`, but those are both key requirements of the type I want to represent.

It seems like the crux of the problem might be "**object type is incompatible with statics of `Base1`**". Is there a different technique I can use to add a static property?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Just looking at the types, `getFoo()` returns `IFoo`, so you should always be able to say `(getFoo(): IFoo);` regardless of what exactly `IFoo` is.

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding the logic here, but this seems to work for some reason:

```
type IFoo = IBase & {+foo: string};
type IFoo2 = Class<Base1> & {+foo: string} | Class<Base2> & {+foo: string};

(Foo: IFoo);  // no error

function getFoo(): IFoo2 {  // change return type to IFoo2
  return Foo;  // no error
}


(getFoo(): IFoo);  // huh?
(getFoo(): IFoo2);
```

[Link](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCM0De0C+AoUkbwgQCY1MsdwpoAxAe1ugQA8AXBAOwBN9EVUto0CCzAsAlsGgAzetAC80AEQALMYqzYsLAJ4AHBNACSBAwoDClCAB4TSAHzQAPtAt4biInYDc5HfqN0DArGiNAAZGgA1DK0AFxCLABOYuwA5hg+WnoGhoEk5pbuhPbhUTHxwslpGE4uhSaepajR9BVJKemZABSB8bn0AJReggD0I9DsDAiJibSJ5FIAruzA4rTs0KkILIFdA315aALQiduLiRuBw9BjE1MzcxoLy6ti65vbeXvxAFRHgqcWOdLvRrk9yF0tjt6N8AoNrrdlItlAB+LCQz4w-Zw2hEIZAA)

I had similar issues of using union of intersection types vs. intersection of union types in the past, usually just try one or the other until it works..